# Nginx high IO issue

Tags: nginx, debian, hard-drive, video-streaming

I run a small video streaming website and i've been noticing some problems with videos on my site.

TOP

```
top - 15:43:48 up 34 days,  1:22,  1 user,  load average: 37.80, 38.08, 38.38
Tasks: 184 total,   1 running, 183 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  0.5 us,  0.5 sy,  0.0 ni,  6.0 id, 85.1 wa,  0.0 hi,  7.8 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 32730324 total,  1575916 free,  1470200 used, 29684208 buff/cache
KiB Swap: 33313788 total, 33308768 free,     5020 used. 30448240 avail Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  16.9  0.0   5554:20 ksoftirqd/0
 2827 www-data  20   0  398696  84756   5548 S   6.0  0.3 213:14.78 nginx
 2828 www-data  20   0  324716  10900   5548 S   1.7  0.0  14:46.99 nginx
   40 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0 148:03.47 ksoftirqd/5
  198 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0  11:16.66 kworker/0:+
 1086 root      20   0   44044   3668   2988 R   0.3  0.0   0:00.21 top
 2829 www-data  20   0  319180   6660   5396 S   0.3  0.0   1:51.37 nginx
27962 root      20   0  109956   9704   7836 S   0.3  0.0   0:00.53 exim4
    1 root      20   0  204648   5072   3644 S   0.0  0.0   1:47.36 systemd
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.16 kthreadd
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0  31:06.23 rcu_sched
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
    9 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:01.11 migration/0
   10 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 lru-add-dr+
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   1:16.83 watchdog/0
   12 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 cpuhp/0
```

IOTOP

```
Total DISK READ :      59.96 M/s | Total DISK WRITE :       0.00 B/s
Actual DISK READ:      59.96 M/s | Actual DISK WRITE:       8.84 K/s
  TID  PRIO  USER     DISK READ  DISK WRITE  SWAPIN     IO>    COMMAND
 2902 be/4 www-data  377.17 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2845 be/4 www-data 1508.66 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2864 be/4 www-data  754.33 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2832 be/4 www-data 1005.78 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2888 be/4 www-data  754.33 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2883 be/4 www-data  848.62 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2836 be/4 www-data 1382.94 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2849 be/4 www-data  628.61 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2841 be/4 www-data  660.04 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.58 % nginx: wo~er process
 2853 be/4 www-data  880.05 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2831 be/4 www-data  754.33 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2859 be/4 www-data 1382.94 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2835 be/4 www-data 1005.78 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.87 % nginx: wo~er process
 2851 be/4 www-data  628.61 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2834 be/4 www-data  754.33 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2839 be/4 www-data  880.05 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2860 be/4 www-data  251.44 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2892 be/4 www-data  628.61 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2843 be/4 www-data  880.05 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.99 % nginx: wo~er process
 2833 be/4 www-data  377.17 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.97 % nginx: wo~er process
 2856 be/4 www-data  754.33 K/s    0.00 B/s  0.00 %  99.97 % nginx: wo~er process
```

When i stop my website and i try to run disk speed this is what i have.

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=tempfile bs=10M count=1024 conv=fdatasync,notrunc status=progress
10622074880 bytes (11 GB, 9.9 GiB) copied, 46.0385 s, 231 MB/s
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
10737418240 bytes (11 GB, 10 GiB) copied, 92.1228 s, 117 MB/s
```

So, current i can push up to 120 MB/s and iotop report i do 60 MB/s, why i'm high load IO issue if only i'm using half speed?

How i can tweak or fix this problem? i'm using nginx to serve mp4 videos.

Comment: Is it a VPS or Dedicated server? What kind of disks are used? Also in your test examples your comparing read speeds with write speeds.